# Wrapfigure not wrapping a description list

Tags: lists, description, wrapfigure

I want to write my CV in LaTeX. I would like to wrap the figure of my photo with the text that describe my personal information. I would like to wrapfigure with a description text. I'm using the following code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{1cm}
  \includegraphics[height=20mm]{Foto-CV.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{description}
  \item[Surname] \emph{my surname}
  \item[Name] \emph{my name}
  \item[Date of Birth:] aa/bb/cccc 
\end{description}
```

When I do this, LaTeX wraps the figure with the text following the description not with the description itself.

Is there something am I missing? Or maybe there is another package better suited for this...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There are so many good classes and packages listed in the »TeX Catalogue« that simplify to compose a CV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with wrapfigure, but if it were me I'd use [minipage](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_43.html)s.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{description}
  \item[Surname] \emph{my surname}
  \item[Name] \emph{my name}
  \item[Date of Birth:] aa/bb/cccc 
\end{description} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[height=20mm]{Foto-CV.jpg}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: `minipage` does not wrap around text, arrange two `minipage`s side-by-side. Two-column layout.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, none of the latex "text wrapping around figure" packages plays well with lists.  The wrapfig documentation says "The environment must not be placed in special places like lists."  In fact, just having it immediately before or immediately after a list may cause trouble.

This is one of the cases where ConTeXt may be a better choice.  ConTeXt does not need a package to wrap text around a figure, you just use the standard ConTeXt `\placefigure` command, and it seems to work just fine with list environments.